# Cannot stop website from redirecting

Tags: wordpress, redirect, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress site, leishinfo.com, that will not stop redirecting. It redirects to a site called intentionandinsight.com/. I thought it might be related to my theme, but after deleting the theme in file manager it still redirects. I cannot access wp-admin either. I have not set up any redirects with my hosting service.

How do I make it stop?

Comment: can you able access the db of `leishinfo.com` site?

Comment: check db or check .htaccess if both are correct than open index.php page add  in first line <?php echo "hii.." ; exit; ?>and check what happen .??

Comment: might be home, or site URL in the DB

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your `wp-config.php`

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://leishinfo.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://leishinfo.com');
```

Or change `siteurl` and `home` in DB. Open `phpmyadmin` and go to `wp_options` table. You will see home and siteurl. Change this to your.

Comment: Thanks! I added the code you mentioned in wp-config. I looked in phpmyadmin and saw the correct site URLs are already defined.

Now the site does not redirect, but the wp-admin page still redirects to the other domain, so I can't edit anything.

Comment: try turn of plugins. If you already checked theme, check plugins! Rename  one each plugin. Like you have `wordpress-seo` rename to 'wordpress-seo_' or something. Plugin will be turned off. And check. Also use private browsing